# Sass function not available from import file

Tags: sass

file1.scss

```
@function toPx($n) {
    @return $n + 0px;
}
```

file2.scss

```
body {
   font-size:toPx(10);
}
```

file3.scss

```
@import "file1.scss";
@import "file2.scss";
```

The output of file3.css contains

```
body {
       font-size:toPx(10);
    }
```

I can't get my toPx function to work, even if I import directly into file2.scss. If I declare toPx inside file2.scss it will work however.

I'm new to SASS so assuming I'm missing something simple here, is anyone able to tell me what?

Surprisingly Scout, the sass compiler i'm using, does not throw an error but simply renders the toPx(10) into the output CSS.

**Edit**

I've found this reference which seems to suggest that I will need to use the Ruby API in order to achieve a global function. Is anyone able to clarify?

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a hack answer, that makes me think it's probably a Scout bug.

I altered file3.scss to this

```
@import "file1.scss";
@import "file2.scss";
body {
       font-size:toPx(10);
    }
```

After compiling that, it worked as intended. Next I changed my files back to how I described in the question and now all my calls for toPx work in any file.